# Verb Хватать/хватить—use мне or у меня?

Tags: грамматика

It seems like one can use either the structure У МЕНЯ or dative МНЕ with this verb in the sense of not enough, or enough of X.

See link—[LINGVO](https://lingvolive.com/ru-ru/translate/ru-en/%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

When should I use one and not the other?

Comment: could you please copy and paste relevant excerpts from the link to the post body? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the sense "to have enough of" they are interchangeable.

> - Повторяю: всем нам хватает (*= у всех нас хватает*) мужества переживать чужие несчастья.
> - Ему хватает (*= у него хватает*) забот в собственной компании.

In the sense "to be enough for" you can only use dative:

> - Лес был не очень большой и не слишком дремучий, но места в нём всем хватало.
> - Хотя для волнений ему хватало и первых впечатлений…

Comment: What about "хватать совести"?

Comment: @V.V.: what about it?

Comment: Там только один вроде вариант.

Comment: @V.V.: what do you mean? Both *ему хватает совести* and *у него хватает совести* seem OK to me.

Comment: А если "не хватило", вообще может быть разный смысл. Им не хватило места. У них не хватило места.

Comment: @V.V.: exactly, that's what I said in my answer.